# unexpect (unwanted) left margin appearing on this navigation

Tags: css, debugging, margin

I have this bare bones navigation that I am putting together and for some reason I am getting about a 40px left margin before the first link starts. I dont have a left margin on the div so not sure why it is happening. Of course it wont look good to be completely flush against the left side of the screen but id like to control any margin size myself.

**I could not use jsfiddle** for this because inside jsfiddle the error is not there. it renders fine.

With that said, this is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer_enhanced {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #121212;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#navigation_enhanced {
    color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
#navigation_enhanced ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#navigation_enhanced li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#navigation_enhanced li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 0.375em;
    padding-right: 0.375em;
    padding-left: 0.375em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
#navigation_enhanced li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.current {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 0.375em;
    padding-right: 0.375em;
    padding-left: 0.375em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer_enhanced">
<div id="navigation_enhanced">
<ul>
<li class="current">home</li>
<li><a href="#">cat2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cat3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cat4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cat5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle applies a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) before any of your styles. Perhaps you need to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unwanted" space doesn't exist in a fiddle by default because they reset (incorrectly labeled as *normalize*) the css.  By default, `ul` has a `padding-left`, but jsfiddle clears it.

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I knew I was overlooking something. It was driving me crazy lol.